# Mark every day from 6:10 pm to 6:40 pm

Tags: pine-script

I have no idea how to accomplish a plot between 6:10 pm and 6:40 pm every day.

I was able to mark Saturdays and Sundays, but I can't do it for specific range hours.

```
var color C_SATURDAY = color.new(color.red, 20)
var color C_SUNDAY = color.new(color.red, 40)

isSaturday = dayofweek == dayofweek.saturday
isSunday =  dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday
bgcolor(isSaturday ? C_SATURDAY : isSunday ? C_SUNDAY : na, title = "Saturdays and Sundays")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to hardcode it, there are already built in functions for time, sessions...etc.

Just input a session time (
`:1234567` from the `sess` input will give you the 7 days session, otherwise it will get only the weekdays ), then create a function to check if it's in session and after that, do whatever you want with it (your example: bgcolor)

```
//@version=4
study("Session", overlay=true)

//Session inputs
sess = input(title="Session", type=input.session, defval="1810-1840:1234567")

//New session
is_session(sess) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, sess))
    
Session = is_session(sess)
bgcolor(Session ? color.green :na)
```